# MongoDB - Is there a boolean AND version of $in?

Tags: mongodb

This operation finds all uploads that have tags "important" OR "school":

```
db.uploads.find({tags: {$in: ['important', 'school']}})
```

What I want do is show only uploads that have tags "important" AND "school." Is this the only way?

```
db.uploads.find({$and: [{tags: 'important'}, {tags: 'school'}]})
```

Comment: The other way is using the [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#equivalent-to-and-operation) operator `db.uploads.find({tags: {$all: ['important', 'school']}})` which is equivalent to using the `$and` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$all` operator:

```
db.uploads.find( { tags: { $all: [ "important", "school"] } } )
```